# Leaving the last 9 characters of a filename in Automator

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a ton of files to rename where we only need the last 9 characters of the file.

The files are currently named as this: FirstName_LastName_000000000.pdf.
Essentially, I want to rename the files so that they are named as such: 000000000.pdf

If somebody can assist with providing a way of doing so that will be awesome.

Comment: Are all the files in the same folder? Are the last 9 characters unique or is there the possibility that the last 9 characters could be duplicated?

Comment: The files are in the same folder. The last 9 characters are all unique and not duplicated.

Comment: Jonah Coloma, RE: "The files are in the same folder. The last 9 characters are all unique and not duplicated" -- If this is a one time thing, see my "Alternate answer per Comment:" at the end of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one of the ways it can be done in **Automator** is by using a **Run Shell Script** *action* with the *example* **bash script** *code* shown further below.

You can create an **Automator** *Workflow*, or *Service/Quick Action*, workflow.

If you do just a **Workflow**, then you will need to add a **Files & Folders** *action*, e.g. **Get Selected Finder Items** or **Get Specified Finder Items**, and then add a **Run Shell Script** *action*.

If you do a **Service/Quick Action**, then you only need a **Run Shell Script** *action*.

If you do choose a **Service/Quick Action** then set it to use **files and folders** in **Finder**.

For the **Run Shell Script** *action*, have its *settings* configured as:

- Shell: `/bin/bash`
- Pass input: **as arguments**
- Replace the *default code* of the **Run Shell Script** *action* with the *example* **bash script** *code*.

The *example* **bash script** *code* uses [**shell parameter expansion**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to slice and dice the *fully qualified pathname* of the file(s) passed to it into the necessary pieces and then *renames* the file(s) using the `mv` *command* with the `-n` *option*, which will not overwrite an existing file, based on the *values* of the sliced and diced pieces of the *fully qualified pathname*.

As *coded*, it uses a [**regex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to only act on *files* that have the following pattern e.g., **FirstName_LastName_000000000** with any extension added, e.g.: `.pdf`

*Example* **bash script** *code*:

```bash
        # f = fully qualified pathname
        # d = directory pathname
        # fn = filename with extension
        # n = filename without extension
        # e = filename extension
        # s = filename suffix (last 9 characters of filename without extension)


    for f in "$@"
    do
        [ -f "${f}" ] || continue
        d="${f%/*}"
        fn="${f##*/}"
        [[ ${fn} =~ ^.*_.*_[0-9]{9}\..* ]] || continue
        n="${fn%.*}"
        e="${fn##*.}"
        s="${n: -9}"
        [ -n "${s}" ] || continue
        mv -n "${f}" "${d}/${s}.${e}"
    done
```

The output of which would be, e.g.: 000000000.pdf

If you want it to act only on `.pdf` *files*, then change:

```bash
[[ ${fn} =~ ^.*_.*_[0-9]{9}\..* ]] || continue
```

To:

```bash
[[ ${fn} =~ ^.*_.*_[0-9]{9}\.[pP][dD][fF] ]] || continue
```

---

Alternate answer per Comment:

> The files are in the same folder. The last 9 characters are all unique and not duplicated

If this is a one time thing and you just want to open **Terminal** to that *folder*, you can use the following *compound command*:

```bash
for f in *.[pP][dD][fF]; do mv -nv "${f}" "$(n="${f%.*}"; printf ${n: -9}).${f##*.}"; done
```

It will act only on **PDF** *files* and rename to the last 9 *characters*. **Note however, no *error handling* other then not overwriting an existing file.**

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **bash script** *code* is just that and does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in the same folder, go to Finder and select all the files you want to rename. Then right-click on them and one of the options is to rename xxx items where xxx is the number of files selected. When you select this option it opens a panel where you can enter how you want the files renamed. Then you can select rename and all the files will be renamed.

Or from the command line use `ls *.ext` where ext is the extension of your file names, in your case pdf. If the ls command listed just the files you want to change the name of use `cp *.ext newFileName.ext` to copy the files to a new file name or use `mv *.pdf NewFileName.pdf`to move the files.

Comment: What the OP wants is not doable per your answer!

Comment: why not?   He want to rename a list of files.

Comment: What the op said is doable by my method. if he truly wants all file names to be 0000000.pdf, he can't do that any way except by putting one file one folder. I don't think he wants that.

Comment: The last 9 characters are unique per file if that needs to be clarified.

Comment: can extra character be added before those nine like a number?  like 01.000000000.pdf

Answer (score -1):

Open Terminal and copy/paste the following code:

`for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f:19}"; done`

This will truncate the first 19 characters from the file names.

Comment: This does not work properly!

Comment: worked for me without any problems in 10.15.4

Comment: You cannot just chop 19 characters from the file names as "FirstName_LastName_000000000.pdf" is just an example. The length of "FirstName" and "LastName" is unknown as it's just a placeholder!

Comment: I will admit I did overlook that issue, but the OP didn't specify that the "FirstName" and "LastName" would be different.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not the first and last names are the same or different, only that he wants the last 9 numeric characters! If the actual filename was e.g. `Jonah_Coloma_000000000.pdf` then your _command_ renames it to `000.pdf` **not** `000000000.pdf`!

Comment: Why don't you use `${f: -13}` instead (13 -> 9 digits + ".pdf"), and loop over `*.pdf`?